# In IOS programming, is a "View Controller" actually a controller?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, viewcontroller

The name "View Controller" in iOS programming is a bit confusing as it includes both words  "View" and "Controller" in the MVC model.  Is "View Controller" actually just another name for Controller (as the view is actually mostly done by the Interface Builder).  Why is it called a "View Controller"?  Is it because this controller does all the view properties updating and event handling as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `UIViewController` lives inside the "Controller" layer of MVC. But it is a special controller that controls and updates a view. View controllers can also handle events because they derive from `UIResponder`.

You can also create general controllers by subclassing `NSObject`. For example an accounts controller that manages accounts etc. You actually find other controller classes in the iOS SDK, e.g. `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

From the *iOS View Controller Programming Guide*:

> For iOS applications, view controllers provide a vital link between an
>   application’s data and its visual appearance. Understanding when and
>   how to use view controllers is crucial to the design of iOS
>   applications. View controllers are traditional controller objects in
>   the Model-View-Controller design paradigm but they also do much more.
>   In iOS applications, view controllers provide much of the logic needed
>   to manage basic application behaviors. For example, view controllers
>   manage the presentation and removal of content from the screen and
>   they manage the reorientation of views in response to device
>   orientation changes.

Answer (score 2):

"Controller" follows the thing being controller.  If I were writing a controller for a chair I would call it a ChairController.  Since a UIView is being controlled, it makes sense to call it a UIViewController right?  The view itself is only responsible for display, but the logic of what to display is up to its controller.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple docs - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> The UIViewController class provides the fundamental view-management model for all iOS apps.

Basically it is the container for your views and handles more logic than just the visual display that your view does.

> Where necessary, a view controller:
>
> - resizes and lays out its views
> - adjusts the contents of the views
> - acts on behalf of the views when the user interacts with them

Answer (score 1):

You should see a "*View Controller*" as a "*Class that controles the view*".

This is a classic [Model View Controller pattern (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

A `UIViewController` has a view of type `UIView` and you update this `UIView` depending on your business objects (Model) for each particular controller.

Also, events that occur on your `UIView`, are sent back to your `UIViewController` for handling them properly.